# Image doesn't get hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing pacman since its a Lab Assignment. And I try to hide food(image) when pacman reaches it. This is the code that I used which is working :

```
if((parseInt(image1.style.left)>=(parseInt(s1.style.left))) && (parseInt(image1.style.left)<=(parseInt(s1.style.left)+100)) && 
        (parseInt(image1.style.top)+30>=(parseInt(s1.style.left) && parseInt(image1.style.top)+30<=(parseInt(s1.style.left)+100)))) 

    {var e= document.getElementById('s1');

    e.style.visibility='hidden';
    }
<img id="s1" src="s.gif" style="position: fixed; top:50; left:100" />
```

Now the problem is that I'm using the exact same code for another food but it is not working. Here it is :

```
<img id="s5" src="s.gif" style="position: fixed; top:150; right:700" />
 if((parseInt(image1.style.left)>=(parseInt(s5.style.left))) && (parseInt(image1.style.left)<=(parseInt(s5.style.left)+100)) && 
        (parseInt(image1.style.top)+30>=(parseInt(s5.style.left) && parseInt(image1.style.top)+30<=(parseInt(s5.style.left)+100)))) 

    {var e= document.getElementById('s5');

    e.style.visibility='hidden';
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's passing the if statement? Seeing as the code snippets are identical the behavior should be the same.

Comment: @DavidLi That is the problem, its not. Even though it should because my code is generic.

Comment: Do you think that I should declare left attribute instead of right in html tag

Comment: a fiddle will help us help you

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. I changed right attribute to left and now it works just fine.